# How to implement ServletContextListener to listen to a message queue? (Tomcat, ActiveMQ)

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

I'm happily improving my **web application** that runs on a Apache **Tomcat**. An **ActiveMQ** JMS server is added to send and receive messages.

I have added a ServletContextListener to listen to my message continuously.
But, **I'm unsure if this is good code for production.** Any advise is welcome.

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.test.JMSContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The Listeren:

```
public class JMSContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        JMSConnector.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        //Nothing
    }
}
```

The Connection:

```
public class JMSConnector {

    static Context context;
    static QueueConnectionFactory factory;

    static {
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
            factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            //TODO
        }
    }

    public static void startListening() {
        try {
            Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
            Queue queue = (javax.jms.Queue) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/Queue");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

            //This MessageListener will do stuff with the message
            MessageListenerImpl messageListener = new MessageListenerImpl();
            consumer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
            connection.start();

            // Start connection or nothing will happen!!!
            connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            //TODO
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

**Is this an advised way or should this be improved?**

*All help is warmly appreciated. Thanks.*

Comment: using this way you have no ability to pool your connection, so the performance will be a problem in production, if the queue is going to have a lot of entries. spring-jms is a good option, consider giving it a try

Comment: @Hossein. Thanks for the pool advise. I have no spring in my existing application. Would it be a good idea to invest in a separate thread? I only need my server to listen to one queue.

Comment: Listening to one queue is one thing, pooling its connection is another thing. If your business logic implies that the data received in the queue must be processed one by one, then you are OK with your current solution. But if you need to process all arriving messages at once, then you need to have pooling mechanism for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen to a message queue from a web application? (Tomcat, ActiveMQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669219/how-to-listen-to-a-message-queue-from-a-web-application-tomcat-activemq)

Answer (score 0):

I have added an improved solution with a Thread.

*Extra help is still welcome :-)*

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.test.JMSContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The Listeren:

```
public class JMSContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new JMSConnector());
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        //Nothing
    }
}
```

The Connection:

```
public class JMSConnector implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory");            
            Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
            Queue queue = (javax.jms.Queue) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/serverQueue");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

            //This MessageListener will do stuff with the message
            MessageListenerImpl messageListener = new MessageListenerImpl();
            consumer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
            connection.start();

            // Start connection or nothing will happen!!!
            connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            //TODO
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

**Is this an advised way or should this be improved?**

*All help is warmly appreciated. Thanks.*